# Can I sort a list of objects by 2 keys?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have the following class (trimmed down):

```
class DiskInstance(object):

    def __init__(self, name, epoch, size)
        self.name   = name
        self.epoch  = epoch
        self.size   = size
```

Then I define a external function (external to the class above):

```
def getepoch(object):
    return object.epoch
```

I then instantiate several objects of this class and append to a list called DISKIMAGES.

I am currently sorting like this:

```
for image in sorted(DISKIMAGES, key=getedate, reverse=True):
```

Is there any way I can sort first by getedate and then by size?

Thx for any help.

Comment: unrelated but there is a missing `:` at the end of `def __init__(...)` that will cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to sort by epoch and then size, this should work:

```
sorted(DISKIMAGES, key=lambda x: (x.epoch, x.size), reverse=True)
```

or as pointed out by @chepner, you can use the `operator.attrgetter` method

```
import operator
sorted(DISKIMAGES, key=operator.attrgetter('epoch', 'size'), reverse=True)
```

Comment: You can also use `operator.attrgetter('epoch', 'size')` in place of the `lambda` expression.

Comment: The point here is that when you sort a list of `tuples`, the sort is recursive on each of the subsequent items in each tuple - much like sorting words alphabetically - `aardvark` comes before `abacus` - just as `('a','a','r','d',...)` would come before `('a','b','a','c',...)`.