# Sorting objects based on two attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble sorting a list of objects based off of their count (an integer) and their name (a string). The output I desire is sorting first primarily by count, and then if there is a tie in count, to sort alphabetically by name.

I currently have a list of Person objects that have the attributes ._name and ._count.
My **str** method is :

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self._name) + ' : ' + str(self._count)
```

If I print them out it comes out as:

```
David : 10
Steve : 5
Josh : 5
Anthony:5
```

and my desired output is:

```
David : 10
Anthony : 5
Josh : 5
Steve : 5
```

Is there anyway I can sort them alphabetically while keeping them in the correct order based on their ._count?

Comment: Another duplicate [Can I sort a list of objects by 2-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678659/can-i-sort-a-list-of-objects-by-2-keys)